# Ionic for iOS: Stuck at splash screen and getting error "Failed to load resource: unsupported URL" for gap://ready

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, url, ready

I'm working on a mobile app that uses Ionic and Cordova. The Android app is working without a problem, but for the iOS version, I'm getting an error that I haven't found a solution to yet.

I think it may be related to the fact that some of the app's .ts scripts are calling this.platform.ready().  When the iOS app runs, it's stuck at the splash screen with a spinner in the middle.  Debugging with Safari shows the error "Failed to load resource: unsupported URL" for gap://ready .

In my config.xml, I've tried putting this in the ios platform section of my config.xml, as well as under the topmost  tag:

```
<allow-intent href="gap://*/*" />
```

I've tried some other suggestions seen on StackOverflow, but so far nothing has helped.  What might I need to do?  Is it as simple as allowing gap:// URIs another way, or is there something else I'd need to do?